# three.js skinned points instead of mesh

Tags: three.js, glsl, fbx

I am importing a .fbx model of an animated robot hand. I want to use a skinned mesh but render gl.POINTS instead of a standard mesh.

Here is my initial (naive) try. I am swapping the individual elements from THREE.Mesh to THREE.Points:

```
  loader.load('/robot-arm-01.fbx', (object) => {

    let children = object.children.map(child => {
      child.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        vertexShader,
        fragmentShader,
        skinning: true
      })
      let points = new THREE.Points(child.geometry, child.material)
      points.position.copy(child.position)
      points.scale.copy(child.scale)
      points.rotation.copy(child.rotation)
      return points
    })
    object.children = children
  })
```

The problem is definitely not in my vertex shader, which I get to play the animation if I don't swap the children array

This gets my model displayed correctly with gl.POINTS, but my animation is simply not kicking in. What am I missing here?

My only idea is to change the three.js mesh's draw call from gl.TRIANGLES to gl.POINTS at runtime. How does one do such a thing and is there a smarter approach to the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the ideal way to do it but it works for me without problem so far. What I did is just copying all `SkinnedMesh` params into the `Points`. Hope this helps

```
getSkinnedPoints(skinnedMesh) {
    const points = new THREE.Points(skinnedMesh.geometry, skinnedMesh.material);

    points.skeleton = skinnedMesh.skeleton;
    points.bindMatrix = skinnedMesh.bindMatrix;
    points.bindMatrixInverse = skinnedMesh.bindMatrixInverse;
    points.bindMode = skinnedMesh.bindMode;
    points.drawMode = skinnedMesh.drawMode;
    points.name = skinnedMesh.name;
    points.parent = skinnedMesh.parent;
    points.uuid = skinnedMesh.uuid;
    points.type = skinnedMesh.type;

    points.isSkinnedMesh = true;
    points.bind = skinnedMesh.bind;
    points.clone = skinnedMesh.clone;
    points.initBones = skinnedMesh.initBones;
    points.normalizeSkinWeights = skinnedMesh.normalizeSkinWeights;
    points.pose = skinnedMesh.pose;
    points.updateMatrixWorld = skinnedMesh.updateMatrixWorld;

    return points; 
}
```